# Could not send data through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send more than one data by AJAX to fetch.php page... but while I try to pass more than one data `fetch.php` does not work, but if I pass one value `fetch.php` work properly..

**ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
            search:txt,
            cusEmail: ajmalhossainopu9@gmail.com
        },
    datatype:"text",
    success:function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

**fetch.php code**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ajmal");
    $output = '';

    $cusEmail = $_POST['cusEmail'];

    $sql = "SELECT 
    medicinName,pricerPerSheet,dealerID,availAbleAt,district,place FROM 
    medicinalinfo WHERE medicinName LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
?>
```

If I remove `cusEmail: ajmalhossainopu9@gmail.com` from AJAX data section it work properly... What is the problem?

Comment: Your code contains SEVERE sql injection (which you should definitely fix!) and you need to put a string in quotes (just like you have with `fetch.php`, `POST` and `text`)

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you.Can you make it clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems correct.Little Bit modification.Like "txt" is variable or not if not add quotes and same with "ajmalhossainopu9@gmail.com". Like below example

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
            search:'txt',
            cusEmail: 'ajmalhossainopu9@gmail.com'
        },
    datatype:"text",
    success:function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: tnx but I had to do `    'cusEmail': '<?php echo $cusEmail?>'    `